# 4b/5b encoder/decoder

Tags: transceiver, encoding

everyone

I am working on a transceiver block as part of a final project for school. Part of the project involves developing a 4b/5b encoder.

The documentation states that I have to "Devise a 4B-5B coding scheme that will guarantee at most 3 consecutive 0’s or 1’s for any input data sequence."

I have come up with the following solution, which I now think may be wrong.

```
#   4B   5B
0  0000 00100
1  0001 00101
2  0010 00010
3  0011 00011
4  0100 01100
5  0101 01101
6  0110 01010
7  0111 01011
8  1000 10100
9  1001 10101
10 1010 10010
11 1011 10011
12 1100 11100
13 1101 11101
14 1110 11010
15 1111 11011
```

I think it may be wrong because encoding two consecutive zeroes (0b0000 0000 -> 0b00100 00100) would result in four consecutive binary zeroes. The solution that I have has this problem, however every other 4B/5B system I've seen on the internet also has this problem.

Is there a way to create a 4B/5B system that limits the number of consecutive zeroes or ones to at most three, or is the documentation simply wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot more problems than the codewords for 0+0; consider 15+15 (110**11 11**011) for instance.

Comment: It's even worse than that; try 11 and 12 or 0 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task that you've undertaken is impossible. There is **provably** no 4b/5b code that satisfies the conditions you've laid out here.

To prove this, consider the set of all 32 possible 5b codewords, numbered 0 through 31 in normal binary order. Of these, 6 are completely unusable:

```
 0: 00000 - contains 5 consecutive 0s
 1: 00001 - contains 4 consecutive 0s
15: 01111 - contains 4 consecutive 1s
16: 10000 - contains 4 consecutive 0s
30: 11110 - contains 4 consecutive 1s
31: 11111 - contains 5 consecutive 1s
```

Since there were exactly 16 codewords starting with 0 and 16 starting with 1, and we've taken away some of each above, we now know that we must end up using some codewords that start with each of 0 and 1. (That is, we can't use a set of codewords that all start with the same bit.) As a result, the following codewords are *also* unusable, as following them up with a codeword starting in 0 or 1 will result in an unacceptable run:

```
 7: 00111 + 1… is four 1s
 8: 01000 + 0… is four 0s
23: 10111 + 1… is four 1s
24: 11000 + 0… is four 0s
```

The same logic applies in the other direction, so the following codewords can also be ruled out:

```
 2: …0 + 00010 is four 0s
 3: …0 + 00011 is four 0s
28: …1 + 11100 is four 1s
29: …1 + 11101 is four 1s
```

The following two can also be ruled out because repeating either one would result in an unacceptable run:

```
 4: 00100 + 00100 is four 0s
27: 11011 + 11011 is four 1s
```

This leaves us with exactly 16 codewords, and there are a number of unacceptable pairs within them, e.g.

```
 20 + 5: 10100 + 00101 is four 0s
11 + 26: 01011 + 11010 is four 1s
```

There are a number of possible ways to reduce the number of codewords to result in an acceptable set, but we've run out of codewords to work with! Any further reductions would put us under 16, and we need that many to encode four bits.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to talk with my TA tomorrow about this. Hopefully he'll be able to clarify exactly what the documentation means, and correct it if it is wrong.

Comment: +1, I think what the documentation should have stated was "not more than 3 zeroes in a row". That would be feasible.

Comment: @Janka Feasible but useless. If your receiver will lose sync on 4 or more consecutive 0s, it'll lose sync on the same number of consecutive 1s as well.

Comment: No? For example, if 1 means "change" and 0 means "no change". As picked up directly from a magnetic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an overall solution for your project here.

There is no solution for code words of 5bits in length that wont result in a loss of information as duskwuff proved. As long as it must be 5 bits, all 4 bit codewords are possible, and no loss of information is allowed then I think there is a problem with the documentation. If at least six 4b codewords dont exist or if its ok to use codewords up to 5 bits then a solution does exist. Also of course a solution where information is lost can easily be created.

In some cases in communication protocols you dont want a certain sequence or several sequences because they are reserved as control characters. For example if the 0000 or 1111 are control characters then they could be used in conjunction with 2b to 5b words to encode any four bit sequence without a loss of information. 0000 could be an end of message and 1111 could be an escape, and in this case you could use all 32 5b words.